# Класс прямоугольник

Tags: java

```
package ua.com.Oreilly;

public class Rect {
    public int x1,y1,x2,y2;

    public Rect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        this.x1=x1;
        this.y1=y1;     
        this.x2=x2;
        this.y2=y2;
    }

    public Rect(int width, int height) {this(0, 0, width, height);}

    public Rect() {this(0,0,0,0);}  
    public void move(int deltax, int deltay){
        x1 +=deltax;
        y1 +=deltay;
        x2 +=deltax;
        y2 +=deltay;
    }
    public boolean isInside(int x, int y) {
        return ((x>=x1) && (x<=x2) && (y>=y1) && (y<=y2));
    }
    public Rect union(Rect r){
        return new Rect((this.x1<r.x1)? this.x1 : r.x1,
                        (this.y1<r.y1)? this.y1 : r.y1, 
                        (this.x2<r.x2)? this.x2 : r.x2,         
                        (this.y2<r.y2)? this.y2 : r.y2);
    }
    public Rect intersection(Rect r) {
        Rect result = new Rect ((this.x1<r.x1)? this.x1 : r.x1,
            (this.y1<r.y1)? this.y1 : r.y1, 
            (this.x2<r.x2)? this.x2 : r.x2,         
            (this.y2<r.y2)? this.y2 : r.y2);
        if (result .x1> result.x2) {result.x1 = result.x2 = 0;}
        if (result .y1> result.y2) {result.y1 = result.y2 = 0;}
        return result;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + x1+", "+y1+", "+x2+", "+y2+"]";
    }
}

package ua.com.Oreilly;

public class RectTest {
     public static void main(String[]args){
         Rect r1=new Rect(1,1,4,4);
         Rect r2=new Rect(2,3,5,6);
         Rect u=r1.union(r2);
         Rect i=r2.intersection(r1);

         if (u.isInside(r2.x1, r2.y1))
             System.out.println("("+r2.x1+", "+r2.y1+")содержится в объединении");
         System.out.println(r1+ "union" + r2+ "="+u);
         System.out.println(r1+ "intersection" + r2+ "="+i);

     }
    }
```

ВОПРОС 1:
Данный метод для объединения прямоугольников?
Что дает этот метод?

```
 public Rect union(Rect r){
        return new Rect((this.x1<r.x1)? this.x1 : r.x1,
```

ВОПРОС 2:

Данный метод проверяет пересечение координат 2-х прямоугольников?
Для чего этот метод?

Что означает: `{result.x1 = result.x2 = 0;}`?

```
public Rect intersection(Rect r) {
    Rect result = new Rect ((this.x1<r.x1)? this.x1 : r.x1,
            (this.y1<r.y1)? this.y1 : r.y1, 
            (this.x2<r.x2)? this.x2 : r.x2,         
            (this.y2<r.y2)? this.y2 : r.y2);
    if (result .x1> result.x2) {result.x1 = result.x2 = 0;}
    if (result .y1> result.y2) {result.y1 = result.y2 = 0;}
    return result;
```

ВОПРОС 3:

Что мы проверяем используя?

```
 if (u.isInside(r2.x1, r2.y1))
             System.out.println("("+r2.x1+", "+r2.y1+")содержится в объединении");
```

Спасибо всем за помощь!!!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, суть данного кода: указываем класс с координатами, прописываем методы,  что дальше? Что с помощью данного кода можно получить?

Comment: Попробую переформулировать вопрос, только короче: "На фига весь этот код?"

Comment: Код из O'REILLY, пытаюсь для себя разобрать пример..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ВОПРОС 1: Данный метод для объединения прямоугольников? Что дает этот
>   метод?

Да. Возвращает новый прямоугольник, в который вписаны прямоугольники `this` и `r`.

> ВОПРОС 2: Данный метод проверяет пересечение координат 2-х
>   прямоугольников? Для чего этот метод?

Возвращает новый прямоугольник - пересечение прямоугольников `this` и `r`. Если пересечения нет, координаты результата - нули (ну почти).

> ВОПРОС 3: Что мы проверяем используя?

Находится ли точка `(r2.x1, r2.y1)` внутри прямоугольника `u`.